# Unable to access solutions of coupled linear differential equations using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parametric-functions

I have the following code that tries to solve for 4 coupled differential equations `Ap1[x]`, `Ath[x]`, `As[x]`, `Aistar[x]` as a function of `x` with a varying parameter `fs`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fp = 6;
ϕ0 = 2.07;
ωp = 2 π*fp;
ωs[fs_] := 2 π*fs;
ωi[fs_] := 2 ωp - ωs[fs];
ωth = 3*ωp;
zchar = Sqrt[LL/CC];
LL = 100*10^-3;
a = 10;(*μm*)
I0 = ϕ0/(2 π*LL);
Ip = r*I0;
r = 0.5;
Cj = 329*10^-6;
CC = 39*10^-6;
l = 2000;

ω0 = 1/Sqrt[LL*CC];
ωpt = ωp/ω0;
ωst[fs_] := ωs[fs]/ω0;
ωit[fs_] := ωi[fs]/ω0;
ωtht = ωth/ω0;

β = Cj/CC;

kpt = ωpt/Sqrt[1 - β*ωpt^2];
kst[fs_] := ωst[fs]/Sqrt[1 - β *(ωst[fs])^2];
kit[fs_] := ωit[fs]/Sqrt[1 - β *(ωit[fs])^2];
ktht = ωtht/Sqrt[1 - β ωtht^2];
Ap0t = (Ip*zchar)/(ωp*LL*I0);

αit[fs_] := (kpt^2*kit[fs]^3)/(8 ωit[fs]^2);
αst[fs_] := (kpt^2*kst[fs]^3)/(8 ωst[fs]^2);
βit[fs_] := ((2 kpt - kst[fs])*kpt^2*kst[fs]*kit[fs])/(16 ωit[fs]^2);
βst[fs_] := ((2 kpt - kit[fs])*kpt^2*kst[fs]*kit[fs])/(16 ωst[fs]^2);
γit[fs_] := ((kpt + kst[fs] - ktht)*kpt*kst[fs]*kit[fs]*ktht)/(8 ωit[fs]^2);
γst[fs_] := ((kpt + kit[fs] - ktht)*kpt*kst[fs]*kit[fs]*ktht)/(8 ωst[fs]^2);

pumpRHS[x_] := (I kpt^5 Ap1[x]^2 *Conjugate[Ap1[x]])/(16 ωpt^2) + (I E^(-3 I kpt x + I ktht x) kpt^3 (2 kpt - ktht) ktht)/(16 ωpt^2)*(Conjugate[Ap1[x]])^2* Ath[x];
thRHS[x_] := (I kpt^2 ktht^3 Ap1[x]*Conjugate[Ap1[x]]*Ath[x])/(8 ωtht^2) - (I E^(I (3 kpt x - ktht x)) kpt^4*ktht*Ap1[x]^3)/(16 ωtht^2);
signalRHS[x_, fs_] := I*αst[fs]*Ap1[x]*Conjugate[Ap1[x]]*As[x] + I*βst[fs]*(Ap1[x])^2*Aistar[x]*E^(I*(2*kpt - kst[fs] - kit[fs])*x) + I*γst[fs]*E^(I*(ktht - kpt - kst[fs] - kit[fs])*x)Aistar[x]*Conjugate[Ap1[x]]*Ath[x];
idlerstarRHS[x_, fs_] := -I*αit[fs]*Ap1[x]*Conjugate[Ap1[x]]*Aistar[x] - I*βit[fs]*(Conjugate[Ap1[x]])^2*As[x]*E^(-I*(2*kpt - kst[fs] - kit[fs])*x) - I*γit[fs]*E^(-I*(ktht - kpt - kst[fs] - kit[fs])*x)*As[x]*Ap1[x]*Conjugate[Ath[x]];


sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Ap1'[x] == pumpRHS[x], Ath'[x] == thRHS[x], D[As[x], {x, 1}] == signalRHS[x, fs], D[Aistar[x], {x, 1}] == idlerstarRHS[x, fs], Ap1[0] == Ap0t, Ath[0] == 0, As[0] == 1, Aistar[0] == 0}, {Ap1[x], Ath[x], As[x], Aistar[x]}, {x, 0, l}, {fs}]
```

Running the above code leads to four solutions for `Ap1[x]`, `Ath[x]`, `As[x]`, `Aistar[x]`. If I try to access one of the amplitudes, say, `As[x]`, such that

```
As[6][1500] /. sol
```

It doesn't return anything at all. How can I access my solutions upon giving fixed values of `fs` and `x`?

Comment: In the definition of `sol`, change the list of functions being solved for to`{Ap1, Ath, As, Aistar}`

Comment: @BobHanlon That did the trick for me! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are complex DEs (have imaginary i in there) so the solutions will, in general, be complex also.  `Plot` will only plot real values so need to extract either the real or imgainary component of the solutions to plol.  Also `ParametricNDSolve` is a bit confussing as it returns solutions with parameters as in `f[p1,p2,...,x]`

First do as Bob suggests:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Ap1'[x] == pumpRHS[x], Ath'[x] == thRHS[x], 
   D[As[x], {x, 1}] == signalRHS[x, fs], 
   D[Aistar[x], {x, 1}] == idlerstarRHS[x, fs], Ap1[0] == Ap0t, 
   Ath[0] == 0, As[0] == 1, Aistar[0] == 0}, {Ap1, Ath, As, 
   Aistar}, {x, 0, l}, {fs}]
```

Now extract the  parameterized functions from `sol`:

```
Ap1F[fs_, x_] := Ap1[fs][x] /. sol;
AthF[fs_, x_] := Ath[fs][x] /. sol;
AsF[fs_, x_] := As[fs][x] /. sol;
AistarF[fs_, x_] := Aistar[fs][x] /. sol;
```

Confirm a solution is complex such as:

```
Ap1F[0.2, 0.4]
(* 6.71593 + 0.0035224 I *)
```

Select either the real or imgainary component of a solution to plot:

```
Plot[Im@AistarF[0.2, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand that the solutions are complex, but I am usually plotting the absolute value of the solutions anyway. Nonetheless, this was useful!